# Why doesn't `sizeof()` work as expected when the argument is a dereferenced pointer pointing to an array?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, sizeof

My problem is when using `sizeof()`, the result is the pointer size not the array pointed to.

Please, help me.

Here is the code.

The first function creates a 2d matrix and the second displays it while the main function performs a test.

```
 #include<iostream>
 template<typename T>
    T** Mat(T vals[],size_t m, size_t n){

        T** mat=new T*[m];

        for(size_t i=0;i<m;i++) mat[i]=new T[n];

        for(size_t mi=0;mi<m;mi++){

            for(size_t ni=0;ni<n;ni++){
                mat[mi][ni]=vals[mi*(n-1)+ni];

            }
        }
        return mat;
    }


template<typename T>
void dispMat2d(T** mat){

    for(size_t mi{};mi<sizeof(*mat)/sizeof(mat[0]);mi++){

        std::cout<<"I'm here "<<sizeof(*mat)/*/sizeof(mat[0])*/<<"\n";

            for(size_t ni{};ni<sizeof(*mat[0])/sizeof(mat[0][0]);ni++){
                std::cout<<"o"<<mat[mi][ni]<<"\t";

            }
            std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main(int c, char* arr[]){

    double v[]={1.0,2,3,4,5,6};

    auto myMat=Mat<double>(v,2,3);


    dispMat2d(myMat);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use `std::size()` but it doesn't accept the arguments `*myMat1` and `**myMat1`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many duplicates for this.

Comment: It would be one thing if you had an array as a parameter, and expected `sizeof` to give you the array size in bytes (it still wouldn't work). But you have `T** mat`, which is "a pointer to a pointer to T". `*mat` is simply "a pointer to T". It's not an array.

Comment: One thing to note is sizeof() is a compile time constant. So if you would call some function with 2 different arrays you have to get the same size regardless if the arrays are different sizes.

Comment: Besides the fact that a pointer is not an array and `sizeof` can't tell you how many elements it has, there's also the issue that `*mat` and `mat[0]` are the same thing, so `sizeof(*mat)/sizeof(mat[0])` is always 1.

Comment: Note that it is possible to have an actual pointer to an array (of fixed size), in which case this does work.  (The array can also have unknown size, but that’s not the same as a size known at runtime.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers do not keep the information whether they point to a single object or first element of an array.

Compare

```
int *p = new int();
```

and

```
int *p = new int[10]();
```

So `sizeof( *p )` in the both cases is equivalent to `sizeof( int )`.

So you have to pass sizes of arrays explicitly.

Pay attention to that the function Mat has a bug.

Instead of

```
mat[mi][ni]=vals[mi*(n-1)+ni];
```

there must be

```
mat[mi][ni]=vals[mi * n + ni];
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays decay into pointers when passed as arguments to functions, so the size information is lost.

One way to make it work is to take the argument as a reference to an array of a specific size.

Example:

```
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

// helper
template<typename T, size_t Y, size_t X>
using mat_t = std::array<std::array<T, X>, Y>;

template<typename T, size_t Y, size_t X, size_t N>
auto Mat(const T (&vals)[N]) {
    static_assert(Y*X<=N, "vals[] too small"); // compile time assertion
    mat_t<T, Y, X> mat;

    for(size_t mi=0; mi<Y; ++mi) {
        for(size_t ni=0; ni<X; ++ni) {
            mat[mi][ni] = vals[mi*X+ni];       // bugfix
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

template<typename T, size_t Y, size_t X>
void dispMat2d(const mat_t<T, Y, X>& mat){

    for(size_t mi=0; mi<Y; ++mi){
        for(size_t ni=0; ni<X; ++ni) {
            std::cout << 'o' <<mat[mi][ni] << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
int main(){
    double v[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    auto myMat=Mat<double,2,3>(v);
    dispMat2d(myMat);
}
```